# Плавные переходы между активностями в Bottom Navigation

Tags: java, android

```
(` bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.select1:
                    break;
                case R.id.statistic:
                    Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Records.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                    break;
            }    `
```

У меня уже раннее были созданы активности, но я  хочу вызывать их через Bottom Navigation 
 Но переход резкий получается.Как сделать плавно , как например в Instagram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Это нужно делать через фрагменты. Или подключить viewpager

Comment: Fragment mFragment = new YourNextFragment(); 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment).commit();
Так?

Comment: Да. Но реализуете лучше через viewpager

Comment: Да,но ViewPager , это не то что я хотел